# 'Ships today if ordered now' message on product page

Tags: magento-1.9, product, custom, product-view, stock

I want to display text between the product price and the availability.

When a product is in stock i want it to display: "Ships today is ordered before 17:00".

**EDIT:** 
I created the attribute 'ships_today' and i have asigned it but it wont show on the product page. This is my code of view.phtml:

```
<?php if ($_product->isAvailable()): ?>
                        <p "class="availability in-stock"><span style="font-weight: bold; color: green;">(<?php echo $this->__('In stock') ?>)</span></p><br>
                    <?php echo $_product->getShipsToday(); ?>
                    <?php else: ?>
                        <p class="availability out-of-stock"><span>(<?php echo $this->__('Out of stock') ?>)</span></p>
                    <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: check my updated answer

Comment: have you reindexed ?

Comment: Still wont show up, have reindexed and deleted the cache

Comment: and check your attribute ships_today has been set to Yes for Visible on Product View Page on Front-end and Used in Product Listing ?

Comment: Yes, all frontend options are set to 'yes'

Answer (score 0):

create a product attribute called `ships_today` of type text and assign to attribute set.Now you can set value to `"Ships today is ordered before 17:00"` to those products which can be shipped today if they order before 17:00

and call this attribute using code `<?php echo $_product->getShipsToday(); ?>` in `template/catalog/product/view.phtml` whereever you need to call

if you want this thing between price and availability then call `<?php echo $_product->getShipsToday(); ?>` after `<div class="price-info"></div>` and before `<div class="extra-info"></div>`

and check your attribute `ships_today` has been set to `Yes` for `Visible on Product View Page on Front-end` and `Used in Product Listing`

Answer (score 0):

You need to load attribute on product page. 
To do it just need to ensure that you checked field 'Visible on product page' when editing setting of attribute. (Catalog -> Attributes -> Manage Attributes and in first Tab from left, check penultimate option - second horizontall tab)

To show attribute you can do alternative method:

```
echo $_product->getData('ships_today');
```

Refresh index and cache on the end to be sure.
Check if product is set to 'In stock' because your attribute is in 'if' statement.

You can debug all possible attributes by:

```
Zend_Debug::dump($_product->getData());
```

This will show you all attributes with your custom one. If is there then problem is in you echo and php code. If it isn't, then you can load your product by load() method.

Source of debug hint: https://www.atwix.com/magento/debugging-hints/

Comment: The product is in stock and the text 'availability: in stock' appears on the frontend. I set the attribute by adding it to the attributeset 'Default' and dragged it under 'General'.

Comment: Can you say what Zend_Debug::dump($_product->getData()); show you?
Maybe it even not show because it is on other type of template because there exist more than one type of product.

Comment: Where would i paste this code to test it?

Comment: `<?php if ($_product->isAvailable()): ?>
                        <p "class="availability in-stock"><span style="font-weight: bold; color: green;">(<?php echo $this->__('In stock') ?>)</span></p><br>
                    <?php echo $_product->getShipsToday(); ?>
                    <?php else: ?>
                        <p class="availability out-of-stock"><span>(<?php echo $this->__('Out of stock') ?>)</span></p>
                    <?php endif; ?>`

Comment: I'm getting nothing.

Comment: i propose to put this
<?php Zend_Debug::dump($_product->getData('ships_today')); ?>
 before your 
<?php echo $_product->getShipsToday(); ?>
Because if there is to many data then Zend_Debug will be to long execute and you get Bad Gateway.
Sorry for that. I get 'null' if the field not exist

Comment: Are you have one default value for this field? 
(Catalog -> Attributes -> Manage Attributes and in SECOND Tab from left which your text)